# admin-ajax.php slows down, but cant figure out which plugin

Tags: ajax, performance

admin-ajax.php slows down, but cant figure out which plugin. Tried to follow these steps: https://woorkup.com/diagnose-admin-ajax-php-causing-slow-load-times-wordpress/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An option is to manually disable all plugins and enable them one-by-one and see when trouble occurse again.

Another option is to use a WordPress profiler. I would highly recommend using [InterconnectIT's WordPress Performance Profiler](https://interconnectit.com/products/wordpress-performance-profiler/). This plugin will profile all or a certain amount of requests and show you what plugins take a long time to load.